# required attribute for image file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I am running with 2 issues:

1. I am using requiredif attribute which is running perfect for other types like textbox,checkbox etc. but for this one it's not working

   [RequiredIf("DoYouAgree", ErrorMessage = "Please upload an image logo.")]
   [DisplayName("Upload Logo")]
   string imgfile { get; set; }

code from view:

```
 @*Browse File*@
     <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
     <br /><br />   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imgfile):
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:38px;" class="grid_2">
        <input type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile" />
    </div>
     <div class="editor-label1 grid_3" style="margin-top:40px;margin-left:80px;" >
        Max file size 299*299 px or 44KB
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:10px;">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.imgfile)
    </div>
    <br />
```

why it's not working for this one.

1. I have other file which only need required attribute but it's also not working when i click on my button without upload an image

Thanks in advance!

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please upload screenshot image.")]
 [DisplayName("Screen Shots")]
 public string ssimgfile { get; set; }
```

view:

```
div style="margin-top:38px; margin-bottom:20px;" class="grid_2">
        <input type="file" name="ssimgfile" id="ssimgfile" />
            <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:4px;">
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ssimgfile)
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does anyone know the solution????

Comment: i know of js validation for files. its not an attribute but it will do the job

Comment: Thanks I did my work with JS

Answer (score 0):

```
I have done my work with javascript:


    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            if ($("input[type=radio]:checked").val() == "True") {
                //Logo Image
                var selectedFile = $('#imgfile').val();
                if (selectedFile == "") {
                    alert('please select valid image logo for marketplace');
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'];
                    if ($.inArray($('#imgfile').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
                        alert("You are permited to select only '\n.jpeg','.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.bmp' formats are allowed.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```